# how to create second node regtest bcoin

Tags: bcoin

I have created a regtest node bcoin, I would like to know how to create the second regtest node to send transactions between nodes and you could also tell me how to generate addresses for the second node through cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/pinheadmz/bcoin-guide/blob/master/week-2-nodes.md for a guide on how to connect two bcoin nodes in regtest. All you really need to do is configure one node to use non-default ports and data directory so the two processes don't collide. You might find the other guides in that repository useful as well, they were written for https://www.summerofbitcoin.org/ mentees fairly recently.